# Terms in the sum

Tags: partial-derivative, weak-derivatives, finite-element-method

Given a multi index $\alpha = (\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_d)$, the order $|\alpha|$ of $\alpha$ is defined by

$$|\alpha|=\sum_{i=1}^d\alpha_i$$

Let $D^{\alpha}u = \prod_{i=1}^{d}(\frac{\delta}{\delta{x_i}})^{\alpha_i}u$
which denotes the classical partial derivative.

I couldn't figure out that what will be all the terms in the following sum:

$$\sum_{|\alpha|=2}D^{\alpha}u$$

Comment: By the given definition, $|\alpha|=2$ is a set of $d$ elements that add up to two. $\sum_{|\alpha|=2}$ is a sum across all such possible sets. $D^\alpha u$ is the function to be applied to each possible set.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Diaz for giving hints. So I suppose, terms in the sum  is going to be as such;

$$ \sum_{|\alpha|=2}D^{\alpha}u =   
(\frac{\delta^{2}}{\delta{x_{1}^{2}}}+\frac{\delta^{2}}{\delta{x_{1}\delta{x_{2}}}}+\frac{\delta^{2}}{\delta{x_{2}^{2}}})  
$$